# How to "bake" NavMesh from script at runtime?

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

how to bake NavMesh in runtime from script. I searched in Google but did not find.
[some rendered scene and buttons including <kbd>bake</kbd>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTjkw.png)

Comment: An image of your code [is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) to create a code block instead.

Comment: You can't ("baking" literally means "compile the results before building"). You will need a 3rd party asset for a runtime nav mesh solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently, Unity doesn't have a way to bake but NavMesh at runtime BUT there is an experimental package that Unity has that allows you bake a NavMesh at runtime. It is very stable package.

There were [tutorials made by Brackeys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CHV1ymlw-P8) in collaboration with Unity.

The demo project is available for [download](https://github.com/Brackeys/NavMesh-Tutorial) on GitHub. You can use in the scripts in there to bake a runtime NavMesh.

I would highly recommend watching the tutorial first.

Here is also the link for Unity's site and [tutorials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/navigation/introduction-and-navigation-overview?playlist=17105) on runtime navmesh.

Comment: The first video you linked just shows how to bake NavMeshes in the editor. The Unity tutorial looks a bit more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEditor.AI; //"Editor" not "Engine"

NavMeshBuilder.ClearAllNavMeshes();
NavMeshBuilder.BuildNavMesh();
```

Comment: Your answer seems to lack details and examples. Please check on how to write awesome answers here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: This depends on the editor, doesn't it? It wouldn't work in a final export. Even if this does work, it wouldn't permanently solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you installed all required packages "AI Navigation"
2. Then you can build the nav mesh by following the code

```
private void GenerateNavMesh()
{
    // Use this if you want to clear existing
    //NavMesh.RemoveAllNavMeshData();  
    var settings = NavMesh.CreateSettings();
    var buildSources = new List<NavMeshBuildSource>();
    // create floor as passable area
    var floor = new NavMeshBuildSource
    {
        transform = Matrix4x4.TRS(Vector3.zero, quaternion.identity, Vector3.one),
        shape = NavMeshBuildSourceShape.Box,
        size = new Vector3(10, 1, 10)
    };
    buildSources.Add(floor);
    
    // Create obstacle 
    const int OBSTACLE = 1 << 0;
    var obstacle = new NavMeshBuildSource
    {
        transform = Matrix4x4.TRS(new Vector3(3,0,3), quaternion.identity, Vector3.one),
        shape = NavMeshBuildSourceShape.Box,
        size = new Vector3(1, 1, 1),
        area = OBSTACLE
    }; 
    buildSources.Add(obstacle);
    
    // build navmesh
    NavMeshData built = NavMeshBuilder.BuildNavMeshData(
        settings, buildSources, new Bounds(Vector3.zero, new Vector3(10,10,10)), 
        new Vector3(0,0,0), quaternion.identity);
    NavMesh.AddNavMeshData(built);
}
```

3. Enable gizmos and open `Window/AI/Navigation` toolbox to see navmesh in runtime
   [image: NavMesh preview]
4. You can see in the code how obstacles are created, if you switch the navigation to the Areas Tab you will see the existing areas or your custom
   [image: NavMesh Areas]

Answer (score -5):

[AlienCode's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66295400/3789665) is perfect for baking NavMesh at runtime,
*since you can't have both* `using` *tags (*`UnityEditor.AI` *&* `UnityEngine.AI`*)*.

I created a separate script and used it for baking NavMesh.
I'm not certain if it only works in the editor or in builds though.

Comment: (*answer above/below* is worse than useless, as the order of answers with same number of votes *do* get ordered variably.)

Comment: You can use both, actually; you just have to declare which import you mean to use. It still isn't a good idea, though, as it renders your project incapable of being distributed to end platforms. UnityEditor is specifically for use with the editor itself, nothing else.